# The prefix 'context' can't be used here because it is shadowed by a local declaration

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, bloc

I have this stateless date of birth input class, read-only. When tapped, it will show a date picker and after the user picked a date, it will send the value to the bloc state, and it will change the state and the value so it shows the picked date from the date picker.
This is the code:

```
class DateOfBirthInput extends StatelessWidget {
  DateOfBirthInput({
    required this.textEditingController,
    required this.focusNode
  });

  final TextEditingController textEditingController;
  final FocusNode focusNode;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<SignUpBloc, SignUpState>(
      buildWhen: (previous, current) => previous.dateOfBirth != current.dateOfBirth,
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Date of Birth',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey[500],
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
              )
            ),
            TextFormField(
              enabled: state.formEnabled,
              controller: textEditingController,
              focusNode: focusNode,
              readOnly: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: '1 January 1990',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey[400],
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
                ),
                suffixIcon: Icon(
                  Icons.calendar_today_outlined,
                  size: 24.0,
                  color: Colors.grey[500],
                ),
                errorText: state.dateOfBirthDisplay.invalid ? 'Please enter your date of birth' : null,
                errorStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
                ),
              ),
              onTap: () async {
                DateTime? datePicker = await showDatePicker(
                  context: context,
                  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                  firstDate: DateTime(1900, 1),
                  lastDate: DateTime.now()
                );
                if (datePicker != null) {
                  String dateOfBirth = DateFormat('dd MMMM yyyy').format(DateTime.parse(datePicker.toString()));
                  textEditingController.text = dateOfBirth;
                  context.read<SignUpBloc>.add(DateOfBirthChanged(dateOfBirthDisplay: dateOfBirth, dateOfBirth: datePicker));
                }
              }
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

In this context, i got an error. This is the context:

```
context.read<SignUpBloc>.add(DateOfBirthChanged(dateOfBirthDisplay: dateOfBirth, dateOfBirth: datePicker));
```

This is the error:

> The prefix 'context' can't be used here because it is shadowed by a
> local declaration.  Try renaming either the prefix or the local
> declaration.

I've tried to change one of the contexts, the `builder: (context, state)`, I've changed to `builder: (ctx, state)`, and still get the same error.

Please help.

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ReadContext/read.html ...likely you could only use `context` later, once the widget had been built. That's why renaming won't help, but you'll have to ditch that local declaration.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think that's the problem @MartinZeitler

Comment: Still no, it's not I'm ignoring the documentation. I've found the solution by the way, It should be `context.read<SignUpBloc>().add`, not `context.read<SignUpBloc>.add`, and it works. Thanks, @MartinZeitler.

Comment: The solution is, it should be `context.read<SignUpBloc>().add`, NOT `context.read<SignUpBloc>.add`

Comment: The `()` is the function call, that may return the instance?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are trying to access the SignupBloc from the signup bloc's builder context, the `context` variable because both of your stateless widget's context and blocbuilder's context are named as `context`

Rename one of your contexts to something else, either `build(BuildContext context)` or `builder: (context, state) {`

You can rename `builder: (ctx, state)` then the error should be gone.

Comment: Hi, I've tried to change it, and still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this change.

```
builder: (ctx, state) {
  //...
  ctx.read<SignUpBloc>.add(DateOfBirthChanged(dateOfBirthDisplay: dateOfBirth, dateOfBirth: datePicker));
},
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried to change it, and still the same error.

Comment: Make sure you don't change for both these - `Widget build(BuildContext context)` and `builder: (context, state)`. You need to change it for only one of these.

Comment: Understood, I only changed the `builder: (context, state)` => `builder: (ctx, state)`, still the same error.